# Uploading xlsx files to R

Tags: package, xlsx

I'd like to upload an xlsx which includes formulas (I don't want the formulas but the numbers in that cells). I tried different packages, e.g. readxl, XLConnect, openxlxs. But I always got NA/0 in the cells where the formulas are. Does somebody know a useful package? Thanks

Ps. I don't want to change the xlsx in a csv...

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy all the formula-generated values, and paste them as values in a new Excel file. Then import the new file.

Comment: I shouldn't do manual steps oder change something in the xlsx, isn't there another opportunity?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).